# Magento2 architecture question

Tags: magento2, stores

I'm new to Magento and I have an  architecture question.
My company is looking to create a B2B website. But I might have to stick with Magento2 CE Edition.

Requirements:

- 2 brands, with different products, different categories on the same website
- quickly change from one brand "space" to another
- home page displaying two different "spaces" where the business customer can select where he wants to shop
- Different prices for each business customers
- shared cart between the two spaces

We also have a B2C website on Magento 1 already online, with same requirements except for the price. It is configured with only one store and two different store views for each brand. Is this the right way to meet to requirements ?
Because from what I've read, I should create two different stores.

Thank you in advance for your assistance with this.
Vincent